# What issues could arise from using class hierarchy to structure the different parts of a configuration setting?

Tags: configuration, class-hierarchy

Here is the context of my question. It is typical that one organizes configuration values into different files. In my case, my criteria is easy editing and portability from one server to another. The package is for Internet payments and it is designed so that a single installation of the package  can be used for different applications. Also, we expect that an application can have different stages (development, testing, staging and production) on different servers.  I use different files for each of the following three categories: the config values that depend only on the application, those that depend only on the server  and those that depend on both.  In this way, I can easily move the configuration values that depend only on the application from one server to another, say from development to production. They are edited often. So, it is worth it. Similarly, I can edit the values that are specific to the server in a single file without having to maintain redundant copies for the different applications. The term "configuration value" includes anything that must be defined differently in different applications or servers, even functions. If the definition of a function depends on the application or on the server, then it is a part of the configuration process. The term "configuration value" appeared natural to me, even it includes functions.

Now, here is the question.  I wanted the functions to be PHPUnit testable. I use PHP, but perhaps the question makes sense in other languages as well. I decided to store the configuration values as properties and methods in classes and used class hierarchy to organize the different categories. The base class is `PaymentConfigServer` (depend only on the server). The application dependent values are in `PaymentConfigApp extends PaymentConfigServer` and those that depend on both are in `PaymentConfig extends PaymentConfigApp`. The class `PaymentConfigApp` contains configuration values that depend either on the application or on the server, but the file itself contains values that depend on the application only. Similarly, `PaymentConfig` contains all conf values, but the file itself contains values that depend on both only.  Can this use of class hierarchy lead to issues? I am not looking for discussions about the best approach. I just want to know, if you met a similar situation, what issues I should keep in mind, what conflicts could arise, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, subclasses are used to *add* or *modify* functionality rather than *remove* functionality. Thus, the single-inheritance approach you suggested suffers from a conceptual problem that is likely to result in confusion for anyone who has to maintain the application if/when you get hit by a bus: the base class provides support for server-specific configuration, but then you (pretend to) *remove* that functionality in the `PaymentConfigApp` subclass, and (pretend to) re-add the functionality in its `PaymentConfig` subclass.

I am not familiar with the PHP language, but if it supports multiple inheritance, then I think it would be more logical to have two base classes: `PaymentConfigServer` and `PaymentConfigApp`, and then have `PaymentConfig` inherit from both of those base classes.

Another approach might be to have just a single class in which the constructor takes an enum parameter (or a pair of boolean parameters) that is used to specify whether the class should deal with just server-specific configuration, just application-specific configuration, or both types of configuration.

By the way, the approach you are suggesting for maintaining configuration data is not one that I have used. If you are interested in reading about an alternative approach, then you can read an [answer I gave to another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673981/design-patterns-guidelines-on-creating-application-product-configurations/27674927#27674927).

Comment: Regarding your proposal, I do not need a config object at run time that contains only application values or only server values. It is only in the source code that I need the separation, The purpose is easy editing and portability of the config files. The idea of having separate config objects at run time for these three categories is a completely different idea, which I did not mention here.

Comment: Perhaps I should make the classes abstract, except the last one, PaymentConfig, which is the only one that needs to be instantiated.